# How to declare a variable with the scope of an html page in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Javascript has global and local variables.

How can I have intermediate scope at html page level ie declare a variable in the page and make it accessible to only functions embedded in that page ?

Comment: That's the default behaviour of global variables already.

Comment: Accessible to only function embedded in the page as opposed to being accessible to other included scripts? Wouldn't namespacing do that?

Comment: There have been a few popular posts on javascript scope. Try looking through old stack overflow questions for the answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javascript has function scope. you can put all of your code for the "html page level" you describe inside a self-executing function to establish an intermediate scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the article.

Answer (score 4):

The global JavaScript scope is only global within one page.

So just make your variable global on that page and use it in your functions.

PS: global variables *outside* of your own namespace clutter the global namespace and may cause problem with other scripts. So it is best practice to create an own namespace and put all your stuff there.

Comment: I don't want my var being accessible from other pages.

Comment: @user310291 I don't believe you understood, what I said. There is nothing "more global" than page scope. So other pages can _never_ access your variables. Maybe what you mean is just a part of a page, like a Portlet for example. But in that case you got your naming confused in my opinion.